# What's the best way to automatically have properties to be of a certain type for each derived class, without making all derived classes generic?

Tags: c#

**Note:** I have to be limited to Visual Studio 2010, and .Net Framework 3.5 as a target framework (I want it to also work on older OSs).

**I'm creating a system of locations and objects for a game.**

Locations and objects can have references to parent locations (or objects) and sub-locations (or sub-objects). It will be a complex structure.

I want to be able to limit types of possible parent locations and sub-locations (or parent objects and sub-objects for any given specific location (or object) without a need to do extra conversions/casts when using those classes in the game code later.

And I want to avoid a need to copy-paste a slightly modified code for each new derived class (for locations or objects) that will be added into the project in the future.

And I'd like to avoid making ALL of those future derived classes Generic.

In other words, I want to write this system just once in base class(es).

Note: All the classes for locations and objects are derived from GameObject class (which will provide a similar behavior when it comes to basic properties, operations, saving and loading, etc.)

---

**Eventually I came up with a possible solution**, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to achieve what I wanted. And it also has a problem!

As an example I will provide the code for some locations, base and derived classes.

**I need to achieve the following goals** for all possible future classes, derived from provided in the example abstract classes (or from classes already derived from them):

1. ParentLocation field / property must always have an appropriate type for supported parent location type(s). No conversions should be necessary.
2. SubLocations generic list must always be an appropriate type for supported sub-location type(s). No conversions should be necessary.
3. The "bottom" sub-locations in their hierarchy should NOT have even empty lists of sublocations at all (no sub-locations should be possible to have for those).
4. *(I couldn't achieve this one in my solution!)* I want to be able to itereate through a collection (let's say a List<>) of locations of different types present in that collection, in order to check different properties shared between all collections (based on their very base object) like "ID", "Name" and so on. (As for accessing the SubLocations proprety, it could be possible by checking if an instance is a LocSubGen class... But there's a problem, since it's generic, so I can't easily check it).

---

**The code of my own solution:**

Note: I'd like all collections to have at least a ParentLocation property, but I didn't find a way to prevent deriving from `Location` base class directly.

Abstract Classes:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Base location
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class Location : GameObject
    {
        protected List<PhysicalObject> objectList = new List<PhysicalObject>();

        /// <summary>
        /// All physical objects inside the location
        /// </summary>
        public List<PhysicalObject> ObjectList
        {
            get { return objectList; }
        }

        protected Location()
        {
            
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Base location that supports a parent location reference
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="P">Parent location type</typeparam>
    public abstract class LocParentGen<P> : Location
        where P : Location, new()
    {
        protected P parentLocation = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Parent location reference
        /// </summary>
        public P ParentLocation
        {
            get { return parentLocation; }
        }

        protected LocParentGen()
        {
            
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Base location that supports a list of sub-locations
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="P">Parent location type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="S">Sub-location type</typeparam>
    public abstract class LocSubGen<P, S> : LocParentGen<P>
        where P : Location, new()
        where S : Location, new()
    {
        protected List<S> subLocations = new List<S>();

        /// <summary>
        /// All sub-locations inside the location
        /// </summary>
        public List<S> SubLocations
        {
            get { return subLocations; }
        }

        protected LocSubGen()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Derived Classes:

```
    public class Galaxy : LocSubGen<Universe, Sector>
    {
        public Galaxy()
        {

        }
    }

    public class Sector : LocSubGen<Galaxy, StarSystem>
    {
        public Sector()
        {

        }
    }

    public class StarSystem : LocParentGen<Sector>
    {
        public StarSystem()
        {

        }
    }
```

**Result (all goals were accomplished automatically):**

```
Galaxy galaxy = new Galaxy(); 
Sector sector = new StarSystem(); 
StarSystem starSystem = new StarSystem(); 

galaxy.ParentLocation; // is Universe
galaxy.SubLocations; // is List<Sector>

sector.ParentLocation; // is Galaxy
sector.SubLocations; // is List<StarSystem>

starSystem.ParentLocation; // is Sector
starSystem.SubLocations; // does NOT exist at all for the class!
```

No conversions/casting is required to access needed instances by those properties.

No extra coding: everything works the moment a new class is derived with setting its parent location and sub-locations' base types.

**The problem with my solution (EDITED):**

I don't see an easy way (and don't know how) to put all future possible instances of locations (derived from LocSubGen<P, S>) into one collection (let's say a List<>) to access their ParentLocation and SubLocations properties. It could be used to check `null` for parents, or to get to other properties shared by ALL locations (it would be IDs, Names, etc.)

For example, I'd like to go through all SubLocations and check their other properties, like Names, etc. (not present in the example code for simplicity).

**My question:** what is a better way to achieve my goals and to solve that problem I got in the end?

Comment: What do you want to be able to access using your `List<Location>` collection? You see, not every location has a parent, and not every location has sublocations. And even if they did, you don't know what type of parent a location in the list has. You only know it's some sort of `Location`. Are you sure this is useful?

Comment: @Sweeper 
I don't see an easy way (and don't know how) to put all future possible instances of locations (derived from LocSubGen<P, S>) into one collection (let's say a List<>) to access their ParentLocation and SubLocations properties. It could be used to check ```null``` for parents, or to get to other properties shared by ALL locations (it would be IDs, Names, etc.) 
P.S. The idea is that future classes must be derived the way they at least have a parent property anyways.

Comment: C# doesn't allow list of generic types - each new T creates a new type and so you can't have a list of AClass<T> but you can have a list of AClass<int>.  The only option is to create a non generic base class or an interface that you then create a list of

Comment: But one of your requirements contradicts that! You said that "'bottom' sub-locations in their hierarchy should NOT have even empty lists of sublocations at all", so what if you try to get the first item in the `List<Location>` and try to get its sub locations, but the first item happens to be a "bottom" sub-location? Or, what if you try to get the parent of the first item, but it happens to be one of the root locations that doesn't have a parent?

Comment: _"I have to be limited to Visual Studio 2010, and .Net Framework 3.5 as a target framework."_ might I ask why? That's 14 yo technology....

Comment: @Sweeper
 The idea is that future classes must be derived the way they at least have a parent property anyways. And before checking for SubLocations I could check if an instance is a specific base class. 
The point is to be able to iterate through some collection of locations and access their properties like IDs, Names, etc. (which aren't present in the example code for simplicity). And all that with keeping the functionality of those parent and sub-location propreties being "auto-set" to necessary types when deriving classes.

Comment: @JHBonarius
I'm an enthusiast in programming, and I have that particular Visual Studio copy for years. Also, I want this application to run on some older OSs, and the optimal target is 3.5 (with the config file being set to be able to run on 4.0+ if it's present of course).

Comment: @Sweeper 
Ok. I just edited my question, clarifying the goals list (adding an extra goal). And I also added this bit before abstract classes code: 
"Note: I'd like all collections to have at least a ParentLocation property, but I didn't find a way to prevent deriving from "Location" base class directly."

Comment: It's quite a complex relationship..._everything_ is a `Location`. Are you sure inheritance is the right method here? You know the "is a" and "has a" difference, right? Also not that you give each `Location` and objectlist. So the even the last 'child' type will have such a list.

Comment: @JHBonarius
I edited my goals list in the question post (added an extra one). 
Well and that's the point: my solution has that big problem. I can't achieve ALL those four goals at the same time. Which is why posted my question. To be able to find a better solution that would cover ALL those goals. Mine is clearly not working fully. Only partially.
I mean, perhaps I could allow the last "child" type to have an empty list of sublocations, if it's necessary for other goals to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to go through all SubLocations and check their other properties, like Names, etc. (not present in the example code for simplicity).

To do that, you can introduce some covariant interfaces:

```
public interface ILocation
{
    // here you can add all the properties common to all locations
}

public abstract class Location : GameObject, ILocation
{
    ...
}

public interface IHasParentLocation<out P> : ILocation where P : Location 
{
    P ParentLocation { get; }
}

public abstract class LocParentGen<P> : Location, IHasParentLocation<P>
    where P : Location, new()
{
    ...
}

public interface IHasSubLocations<out P, out S> : IHasParentLocation<P> where S : Location
{
    IEnumerable<S> SubLocations { get; }
}
public abstract class LocSubGen<P, S> : LocParentGen<P>, IHasSubLocations<P, S>
    where P : Location, new()
    where S : Location, new()
{
    // explicitly implement the interface
    IEnumerable<S> IHasSubLocations<P, S>.SubLocations 
    {
        get { return SubLocations; }
    }

    ...
}
```

Now, you can create a `List<Location>`, or even a `List<IHasParentLocation<Location>>` if you are sure that all locations have a parent. Since `IHasParentLocation` is covariant, it is possible to add things like `IHasParentLocation<Galaxy>` to a list of `IHasParentLocation<Location>`.

To iterate through the sublocations, simply:

```
foreach (var location in list) 
{
    // again making use of the covariance here
    if (location is IHasSubLocations<Location>) 
    {
        var sublocations = (location as IHasSubLocations<Location>).SubLocations;
        foreach (var location in sublocations)
        {
             // location is of type Location here
        }
    }
}
```

Although this should work, I feel like the concrete locations inheriting from abstract classes doesn't feel "right". I'd prefer to have only 2 types here: `Location` and `LocationWithSubLocations`. Galaxies, sectors and others should be *instances* of these, rather than subclasses. In case some of the methods in `Location` have different implementations between `Galaxy` and `Sector`, use the strategy pattern: use an instance of `ILocationStrategy` to instantiate `Location`s, and delegate the method calls to that.

Though, this wouldn't work if `Galaxy` and `Sector` have public methods that are unique to them.

Comment: Interesting solution! 
Sadly it looks like it's not supported on Net Framework 3.5 (which I wanted to use so that some older OSs could run this application as well). 
Unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: @InvisibleManX What's not supported? I deliberately even checked! VS 2010 comes with C# 4, right?

Comment: I see. What confused me was this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853857/optional-parameters-work-in-target-framework-3-5-while-covariance-and-contravari

Comment: @InvisibleManX If you use the C# 4 compiler, you should be fine.